# Cross validation in cross_val_score

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation

When fitting my data in python I'm usually doing:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

I splits my data into two chunks: one for training, other with testing.

After that I fit my data with:

```
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test,y_test)
```

And I can get the accuracy with:

```
accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)
```

I understand these steps.
But what is happening in `sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score`? For example:

```
cross_val_score(estimator= model, X= X_train,y=y_train,cv=10).
```

Is it doing everything that I did before, but 10 times?

Do I have to split the data to train,test sets? From my understanding it splits the data, fits it, predicts the test data and gets the accuracy score. 10 times. In one line.

But I don't see how large is the train and test sets. Can I set it manually? Also are they same size with each run?

Answer (score 0):

The function "train_test_split" splits the train and test set randomly with a split ratio.

While the following "cross_val_score" function does 10-Fold cross-validation.

```
cross_val_score(estimator= model, X= X_train,y=y_train,cv=10)
```

In this case, the main difference is that the 10-Fold CV does not shuffle the data, and the folds are looped in the same sequence as the original data. You should think critically if the sequence of the data matters for cross-validation, this depends on your specific application.

Choosing which validation method to use: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103459/how-do-i-know-which-method-of-cross-validation-is-best

You can read the docs about K-Fold here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, if you set `cv=10`, it will divide your dataset into 10 folds. So if you have 1000 rows of data, that's mean 900 will be training dataset and the rest of the 100 will be your testing dataset. Hence, you are not required to set any `test_size` like what you did in `train_test_split`.